# Spring Security custom PermissionEvaluator configurations does not work properly

Tags: spring, security, configuration, autowired, access-control

I have a problem with my custom Spring Security PermissionEvaluator. So, 
the CustomPermissionEvaluator needs that service to do its work.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  // methods....
}
```

And here's the evaluator itself.

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

   private MyService service;

   public CustromPermissionEvaluator( MyService service ) {
     this.service = service;
   }

   // hasPermission methods... 


}
```

And here's configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration  {

  @Autowired
  private MyService service;

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {

    CustomPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator = new CustomPermissionEvaluator( service );

    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator( permissionEvaluator );

    return expressionHandler;

  }

}
```

So when @PreAuthorize( "hasPermission( ... )" ) should be invoked, nothing happens. But when I put that dependency straight to the CustomPermissionEvaluator's constructor, without ApplicationContext and autowiring, everything works perfect. I have printed service object to the log file and it is not null. So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and had to use the `@Lazy` annotation:

```
@Lazy @Autowired
private MyService service;
```

It appears the security stuff is bootstrapped before the rest of the Spring config.  I guess `@Lazy` allows a reference to be injected but not actually resolved until used.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours , this is the only solution solution worked for me. thanks @hvgotcodes.

so what i did is
annotate the CustomPermissionEvaluator with @component. 
and annotate MyService with @Lazy @Autowired

```
@Component
Class CustomPermissionEvaluator {
    @Lazy @Autowired
    private MyService service;
}
```

If I user the `@Lazy @Autowired`  in configuration MethodSecurityConfiguration then it does not worked